# Serilog, Open Telemetry and Azure App Insights

Tags: azure, serilog, open-telemetry

I'm using .net core (8) and have Serilog enabled and am using Open Telemetry to push traces to Azure App Insights. I'm using the correct format in Serilog:

`Log.Information("test {@msg}", msg);`

All is working but the 'Custom Dimensions' only show the message type and I don't see the structured log. I can serialize the model but that defeats the point of having structured logging in the first place. I've tried all sorts but nothing seems to change this. Here's how I've wired up Open Telemetry and Serilog.

```
services.AddOpenTelemetry()

            .ConfigureResource(builder => ConfigureResource(

                builder, 

                cfg.GetSection("Application:Name").Value ?? "", 

                cfg.GetSection("Application:Version").Value ?? ""))

            .WithTracing(x => x

                .AddSource(DiagnosticHeaders.DefaultListenerName)

                .AddAzureMonitorTraceExporter(o =>

                {

                    o.ConnectionString = cfg.GetSection("AzureServiceBus:ApplicationInsightsConnectionString").Value;

                }))

            .WithMetrics(x => x.AddMeter(InstrumentationOptions.MeterName)

                .AddAzureMonitorMetricExporter(o =>

                {

                    o.ConnectionString = cfg.GetSection("AzureServiceBus:ApplicationInsightsConnectionString").Value;

                }))

            .UseAzureMonitor();
```

````
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()

                    .MinimumLevel.Information()

                    .WriteTo.Console()

                    .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", cfg["Application:Name"])

                    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(

                        cfg["AzureServiceBus:ApplicationInsightsConnectionString"],

                        new TraceTelemetryConverter())

                    .CreateLogger();```
````

Comment: Can you please share your configuration file.

Comment: Can you share your current output and also a sample output which you want.

Comment: Try using `Log.Information("test {Message}", new { msg, CustomProp1 = "Val1", CustomProp2 = "Val2" });` and check once.

Comment: The config just has an app insights connection string which is working ok

Comment: Can you share the screen cap of transaction search (custom telemetry)

Comment: Did 
Did the step above with Log.Information("test {@message}", new { msg, CustomProp1 = "Val1", CustomProp2 = "Val2" });

This came in the trace!

@message
{ message = MyMessages.MyUpdateMessage, CustomProp1 = Val1, CustomProp2 = Val2 }

Not sure you can do screenshots in the comments

Comment: Seems to log all the props if it's a record and not a class (that inherits from a base message)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257163/discussion-between-harshitha-and-matt).

Comment: I think I've fixed this. I hadn't called UseSerilog. It was still using the built in MS logger. Now I can see structured logs!!!

Thanks for replying to me https://stackoverflow.com/users/19648279/harshitha

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed this. I hadn't called UseSerilog. It was still using the built in MS logger. Now I can see structured logs!!!